# How can a new instance of an object also be a constructor function

Tags: arrays, function, object, constructor, new-operator

I am struggling to understand this concept. If an an Array object is a new instance of an Object object then how can it also be a constructor. If we create our own constructors the new instances don’t have their own constructors, they are just new instances of the constructor you created

```
 var Person = function (name, age) {
 this.name = name;
 this.age = age;

 }

 var kevin = new Person (“kevin”, 35)
```

Now I wouldn’t surely be able to use The variable kevin as a constructor function. It is merely a new instance of The Person constructor.

So if an Array is a new instance of the Object object then how does it also manage to be a constructor function for all the instances of it to be created !
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
   var Person = function () {

   }

  Person.prototype.saySomething= function () {

        alert("say something");
  }


 new Person (  Dave = function () {  // this is a new instance of a Person object                                        passing in Dave

})

 Dave.prototype.sayNothing = function () {

      alert(" ");

 }

 var sportsman = new Dave();  // this is a new instance ofthe Dave object 
 sportsman.sayNothing(); // this works
 sportsman.saySomething();// this doesnt , however 
 sportsman.hasOwnProperty("blue") // returns false so this works
```

This is what i mean, this is how it should work in my head by sportsman,saySomething doesnt work, states its not a function but i thought it would recognise the Person function prototype and pick it up from there using the prototype chain. It still however picks out the methods from the object object protoype, why doesnt it recognise the prototype of Person if Dave is a new instance of person and sportsman is a new instacne of Dave, thanks